# SAS DI (Data Integration): Inserting a Data in an existing Table

Tags: sas, sas-macro, sas-dis

I have a program in SAS 9.3 (please refer below) that I need to do in SAS Data Integration Studio:

```
%macro sqlloop;
  Proc SQL;
   Select distinct(DATE) into :raw_date from RAW;
  Quit;
  %DO k= %sysevalf("&raw_date"d) %TO  %eval(%sysfunc(today())-1);
   PROC SQL;
    insert into CONSOLIDATED (BRANCH_CD, RC_NAME, DATE)
    select BRANCH_CD, RC_NAME, &k.
    from RAW;
   QUIT;
  %END;
%mend;
%sqlloop;
```

To do this in SAS Data Integration Studio, I did the step and the code inside the "User Written" below:

> RAW ------> User Written -----> Table Loader -----> Consolidated

```
 %let output= &_output;
 %let MySYSLast= &SYSLast;
 %macro sqlloop;
  Proc SQL;
   Select distinct(DATE) into :raw_date from &MySYSLast;
  Quit;
  %DO k= %sysevalf("&raw_date"d) %TO  %eval(%sysfunc(today())-1);
   PROC SQL;
    insert into &output (BRANCH_CD, RC_NAME, DATE)
    select BRANCH_CD, RC_NAME, &k.
    from &MySYSLast;
   QUIT;
  %END;
 %mend;
 %sqlloop;
```

However, I am receiving an error in running this in SAS DI. May I know how to do this properly in SAS DI?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Please include the error message when you post any question asking for feedback to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you require a user written transformation to insert data into existing table when we have load technique -> append to existing available. why to use user written & loader transformation for doing the same work.

Answer (score 0):

For what so-ever reason you are using a User written code, which should be avoided in the first place in SAS DI studio, you can re-arrange your code as below to work,

```
* Remove the 2 %LET statements as DI studio generates code for it already;
%macro sqlloop;

   proc sql noprint;
     /* change the &MYSYSLAST to &_INPUT, this is the first input you connected to the transform */
     select distinct(date) into :raw_date from &_INPUT. ;
   quit;

   %do k= %sysevalf("&raw_date"d) %to  %eval(%sysfunc(today())-1);

      proc sql noprint;
         /* Change the &OUTPUT to &_OUTPUT as that is the standard output for the UW Transform in SAS DI */
         insert into &_OUTPUT. (branch_cd, rc_name, date)
         select branch_cd, rc_name, &k.
         from &_INPUT. ; /* Change &mysyslast to &_INPUT
      quit;

   %end;

%mend sqlloop;

%sqlloop;
```

**NOTE:** You can generate code in UW transform by setting code generation mode to **"User written Body"** [image: UWC with User Written Body selected in DropDown]
or if you dont want the code to be generated then you can use **"All User Written** from dropdown [image: All User Written]